# Why is ESLint throwing warning about unused variable that's used?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

I've been writing React & ES6 code for about 2 months now. Not sure if I just haven't ran into this problem, or if I'm having a brain freeze this morning.

Did some research and ran into a bunch of articles on `const` & `let` but nothing address this. I've been reading that you don't need to use `var` anymore, so then how would you handle this situation?

```
function () {
  let variable = null;

  if (condition) {
    variable = 'hello world';
  }

  console.log(variable); // want 'hello world' if condition
}
```

Edit: please assume function is being called & condition is `true`.

I see the code works under these conditions but my confusion is this: before I referenced the variable in the console log, my ESlint reports `[eslint]: 'variable' is assigned a value but never used`.

Isn't it being used?

Comment: ``let`` is block scope .  and ``const`` is also block scope but you cannot set the value again once it is initialized .

Comment: why not `if (condition) console.log('hello world')`?

Comment: Your code is fine. It logs `null` or `hello world`. Whats the problem?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm just trying to indicate that I need to use that var outside of the block scope again.

Comment: @bot19 can you help us to understand what the problem is? From what we can tell, this code would be no different than if that variable were to be declared with `var`. What are the circumstances that you're not telling us?

Comment: Sorry I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: So, this is now an ESLint question?

Comment: @bot19 the key phrase in your question is "before I referenced the variable in the console log". ESLint is recognizing that you performed some logic and stored the result in a variable that wasn't being used, so it's pointing out that you either need to return it or not use a variable at all.

Comment: The variable scope of const/let is defined by where you declare the variable, not assign a value. If you declare the variable outside the `if` but assign the value `'hello world'` inside the `if` then you can still access the value outside of the `if`.

Comment: Could be. The condition is true, I'm clearly using it. Is it me or ESlint?

Comment: By "using it", ESLint is referring to actually putting it to some use. Simply putting a value in it does not constitute using it, as far as ESLint is concerned. A variable whose value is never accessed serves no purpose.

Comment: @JLRishe - thanks!! That was where my confusion was. I would upvote and marked answered but it's a comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "using it", ESLint is referring to actually putting it to some use. Simply putting a value in it does not constitute using it, as far as ESLint is concerned.

A variable whose value is never accessed serves no purpose.

Answer (score 2):

so its an eslint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars

if you are not familiar with what does eslint do:

> Its goal is to provide a pluggable linting utility for JavaScript

if you think you wanna remove this rule you can add this line to .eslintrc

```
nikko:cms-v3 nikko$ cat .eslintrc.json
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "no-unused-vars": "off", // add this
```

> Isn't it being used?

it doesnt matter if function is called or not, if eslint sees you define a variable in that scope but you never used the variable, it will spit that error. What you did was re-defining the variable not using it.

`let variable` needs to be somehow consumed by some process